# SlickGrid : How to stop certain columns from being reordered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slickgrid

I need to stop certain columns in SlickGrid from being reordered. I just couldn't find a way for it. There is no option on each column to allow reordering as in case of 'resizable' or something like that. The below flag makes all the columns 'reorder-able' :

```
var options = {
  enableColumnReorder: true
};
```

Do let me know if there is any workaround. TIA

Comment: there is a bit of fuzziness in the definition of 'stop a column from being reordered'. For example, you might want a left hand or right hand column to be fixed in that position. Or, you might want three columns to appear next to each other in a particular order in the grid, but still allow other columns to be dragged to the left or right of the group. These would require quite different solutions.

Comment: I understand the point @Ben. So, in my case I had to stop 5 'frozen' columns on the left of the grid from being reordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no direct options to achieve this, but if we explore source code we will find out that they use jquery sortable plugin. So we can "inject" into sortable call to add option `cancel` or `items` for `sortable plugin.

In column options:

```
headerCssClass: "disable-reorder"
```

In initialization:

```
var origSortable = $.fn.sortable;
$.fn.sortable = function (options) {
  if (options !== null && typeof options === 'object'){
    options.cancel = '.disable-reorder';
  }
  return origSortable.apply(this, arguments);
};

data = [
  //some data
];
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

That will prevent headers with class `.disable-reorder` to be not reorderable.

This is ugly and hacky way, but I couldn't found any other options.

[Full fiddle](http://codepen.io/JokerNN/pen/PpPWza)

Comment: It ain't ugly... "You gotta do, what you gotta do". Thanks a lot. I will try to work around on the similar lines and see if I can implement that into my SlickGrid (we have a wrapper written over 'SlickGrid' in the organization :/ ) . But this is of great help.

Comment: I did it another way but I suppose your answer was a cleaner approach of the two. Hence accepting the answer.

Comment: Really glad this helped :)

Comment: FYI there are a couple of  'frozen columns' implementations, none that recently updated https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/530. It's on my list to apply my updates to the JLynch repository (we decided rather than try to merge the two, it's easier just to 'catch up' the jLynch code.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can explicitly disable column reorder and set each column you need `sortable`.

For example:

```
var columns = [
    { id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title", sortable: false },
    { id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration", sortable: true, formatter: dayFormatter },
    { id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete", sortable: true },
    { id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start", formatter: dateFormatter, sortable: true },
    { id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish", formatter: dateFormatter, sortable: true },
    { id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven", sortable: true }
  ];
```

Taken from their example [here](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-multi-column-sort.html)

Addition: docs for column options - https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Column-Options

Comment: 'sortable' flag makes the column sortable, i.e., on click of the header, the rows will be sorted alphabetically. I am looking for such flag which will make the columns reorder-able. :/